# jfreechart: Gantt Chart Task Label Font Size

Tags: fonts, jfreechart, gantt-chart

I put my Gantt Chart (ChartPanel) in a JScrollPane，and create a button named [zoom in].
The function for the button [zoom in] is:
When I click [zoom in] button, the width of chart panel will be doubled.

```
newSize = originalChartWidth * 2;
chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(newSize, 1000));
```

After click [zoom in] button, the scroll bar of JScrollPane will be appeared.
Then the user can scroll to watch the whole chart after zoom in.

But there is a problem, When I double the chart panel width, The Task Label Font will be enlarged too.

Before zoom in
[image]

After zoom in (The font will be deformed and hard to read)
[image]

Is there any way to keep the original font after I double the chart panel width?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117154).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to solve my problem.

Call ChartPanel.setMinimumDrawWidth/Height with small value and ChartPanel.setMaximumDrawWidth/Height with large values than exceed the screen size of your monitor. Then, the ChartPanel will be scaled without being distorted.

Please refer to:
[How to aviod axis label and legend scaling](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117097)

Comment: A [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem & solution you describe would make this a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Absent a complete example, this appears to be an artifact of adding a `ChartPanel` directly to a `JscrollPane`. Instead, use a [`SlidingGanttCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/gantt/SlidingGanttCategoryDataset.html) which permits the use of `setFirstCategoryIndex()` in response to a scrollbar state change. [`SlidingGanttDatasetDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) is a complete example.