# Gantt chart: freeze legend and axes when scrolling

Tags: java, jfreechart, gantt-chart

In the chart factory and I use there `SlidingGanttCategoryDataset`. But the scrolling does not appear. What am I missing?

```java
public JFreeChartGanttChart(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) {
    super(applicationTitle);

    // based on the dataset we create the chart
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> labels = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createGanttChart(chartTitle,
                                                     "Vessels",
                                                     "Time",
                                                     createDataset(labels),
                                                     true,
                                                     true,
                                                     true);

    // Adding chart into a chart pane
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.001);
    plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerMargin(0.01);
    plot.getRangeAxis().setUpperMargin(0.01);
    plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.001);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1500));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);

    CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelGenerator(new IntervalCategoryItemLabelGenerator(){
        @Override
        public String generateRowLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row) {
            return "Text ... " + row ; //  not needed here
        }

        @Override
        public String generateColumnLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int column) {
            return " Text ... " + column; //  not needed here
        }

        @Override
        public String generateLabel(CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column) {
            return labels.get(row).get(column) ;  // row+ " " + column
        }
    });

    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelsVisible(true);
    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelPaint(Color.BLACK);

    renderer.setDefaultItemLabelFont(new Font("arial", Font.PLAIN, 6), false);

    // setDefaultPositiveItemLabelPosition - text will be inside label
    renderer.setDefaultNegativeItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE6,
                                                                       TextAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use a more realistic preferred size, say 800 x 600? What layout? Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: See also `SlidingGanttCategoryDataset` or the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27773120/230513).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for reply. I need such size because the time horizon is one year and I need to scale it without distortion both on x and y axis. I have added second picture which shows that when I scroll horizontally the y axis lables are gone i.e. scrolled with chart conent. How to freeze axis labels and scroll only inne chart content

Comment: I added a bit more of code. The function which creates the dataSet using SlidingGanttCategoryDataset (see at the bottom) which is then used in the first block of code

Comment: I understand your settings for the draw size, but not the _preferred_ size. Are you switching to `SlidingGanttCategoryDataset`?

Comment: the last line in `private static GanttCategoryDataset createDataset` method...Originaly while i create data set I use `TaskSeriesCollection dataset`. Finaly I use `return new SlidingGanttCategoryDataset(dataset, 0, labelTaskCounter);`   see the last line in the secon block of code. This dataset is used then in teh first block of code like `JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createGanttChart(chartTitle, "Vessels", "Time", createDataset(labels),
                true, true, true);` when returned from method `createDataset(labels)`

Comment: The thing is that the scroller works without `SlidingGanttCategoryDataset`, I just enable scrolling by creating `JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(chartPanel);`

Comment: I've outlined an approach below.

Answer (score 1):

While it is technically possible to add a `ChartPanel` to a `JScrollPane`, rendering and scrolling hundreds or thousands of tasks scales poorly; the typical appearance is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71207836/6). Instead, use a [`SlidingGanttCategoryDataset`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/data/gantt/SlidingGanttCategoryDataset.html), which "presents a subset of the categories in an underlying dataset." Given an arbitrary number, `N`, of tasks to to be displayed `MAX` at a time, construct the corresponding dataset:

```
private static final int N = 1000;
private static final int MAX = 12;
…
private final SlidingGanttCategoryDataset dataset = new
    SlidingGanttCategoryDataset(taskSeriesCollection, 0, MAX);
```

Then add a suitable control adjacent to the `ChartPanel` and listen for changes; update the dataset's first displayed index accordingly:

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, N - MAX, 0);
slider.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
    dataset.setFirstCategoryIndex(slider.getValue());
});
```

[image]